# android 11 (api 30): recording voice in background service no working

Tags: java, android, service

for recording call and voice in background on API 29 and lower , i don't have any problem (i use receiver and background service together)
but when i using API 30 and above , my app crashed `permission denied`.

in my research i get must use `accessibility service` but i don't know how!

```xml
<service
     android:name=".recordService"
     android:process=":remote"
     android:foregroundServiceType="microphone"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>

<receiver
    android:name="ReceiverSMS"
    android:process=":remote"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <!-- BROADCAST_SMS -->
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
       <!-- CALL -->
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

```java
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(__FILE__);
```

Comment: Are you certain you've added mic permissions to your Manifest, and that they've been accepted?

Comment: yes! but can't get `allowed all time `

Comment: you mean this -> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

Comment: Correct. And well, starting with Android 11 you cannot have microphone permissions to be "allowed all of the time" -- check out this link for more info: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#one-time

Comment: yes i know, but how some app can record call in background?

Comment: i think can do that with `accessibility service ` but i don't know how

Comment: I've never used an `AccessibilityService` but this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService seems to imply that is meant for disabilities and such.  Are you using a background or foreground service to do the recordings? Perhaps try the alternative

Comment: background. why?

Comment: found any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

To allow voice recording in Service you can use [ref](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types)

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <service ...
        android:foregroundServiceType="microphone" />
</manifest>
```